# Unable to create criteria query with dynamic value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

i am trying to create criteria query with dynamic fields

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<Abc> abc = cq.from(Abc.class);
List<Selection<?>> selectList = new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
if(id != null){
    selectList.add(cq.select(abc.get("id")));
}
if(summary != null){
    selectList.add(cq.select(abc.get("summary")));
}
cq.multiselect(selectList)
```

the above code gives exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.Selection

this is type cast issue but is there any way to implement dynamic values in multiselect

Comment: *what* error???

Comment: Did you mean `abc.get(id)` and `abc.get(summary)` without quotation marks?

Comment: Should `selectionList` be `selectList`?

Comment: an exception is **not** a syntax error.

Comment: it had earlier .i corrected that code :)

Answer (score 0):

The second line of your snippet seems to be causing your issue so I altered it and added a semicolon on the last line.
Try this instead:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<Abc> abc = cq.from(Abc.class);
List<Selection<?>> selectList = new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
if(id != null){
    selectList.add(cq.select(abc.get("id")));
}
if(summary != null){
    selectList.add(cq.select(abc.get("summary")));
}
cq.multiselect(selectList);
```